# Two Capturing Groups in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have string such as

```
(1)ABC(Some other text)
(2343)DEFGHIJ
(99)Q
```

I wanted a regex that would capture these strings into two groups like so

```
ist: (1) 2nd: ABC(Some other text)
1st: (2343) 2nd: DEFGHIJ
ist: (99) 2nd: Q
```

So I wrote this Regex

```
var regex new Regex("^\\((\\d+)(.*)\\)");
Match match = regex.Match(str);
```

But instead of the two groups I expected I get three groups

In the first example I get

```
(1)ABC(Some other text)
1
)ABC(Some other text
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Change your regex to `"^\\((\\d+)\\)(.*)"`

Comment: There will always be n+1 matches (where n is the number of groups in the pattern). The match in the 0th-index is the entire string. It is documented in MSDN: If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object (the element at index 0) returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern [original: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: and you should really use the `@`, like `@"^\((\d+)(.*)\)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is probably

```
@"^(\(\d+\))(.*)"
```

You reversed the order of the `(`. Note that the groups will be 3, because as someone pointed out, the group 0 is all the matched text. So

```
string str = "(1)ABC(Some other text)";
var regex = new Regex(@"^(\(\d+\))(.*)");
Match match = regex.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{
    string gr1 = match.Groups[1].Value; // (1)
    string gr2 = match.Groups[2].Value; // (Some other text)
}
```